# responsive topsheet on background html5 video

Tags: css, html

I need to cover the html5 background video with black responsive layer with some opacity (let's call it "shadow layer"). Unfortunately, I can't pick a height of the video layer, because it has to be absolutely positioned, so it is not possible to pick the height of parent div.

Any advices? JS is absolutely not welcome.
Here is the code:

html

```
<div>
    <div class="shadow-layout">
        <div class="content">
            Some content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="video-bg">
        <video class="video-bg" autoplay loop poster="">
            <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.shadow-layout {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
.content {
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
#video-bg, .video-bg {
    width: 100%;
}
```

...and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7cqprLz/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your css to this...

```
.shadow-layout {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}

#video-bg, .video-bg {
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;
   position:absolute;
}
```

And you should close your source tag... Change your html to this...

```
<div>
    <div class="shadow-layout"></div>
    <div id="video-bg">
        <video class="video-bg" autoplay loop poster="">
            <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/DivakarDass/k7cqprLz/1/

Hope you asked for a background for that video like this.

Cheers.

Comment: hi and thx for answer! seems like there is a misunderstanding: i have a need not in background for a video, but a half-transparent black layer which would cover the video. And the video actually has to be the background for some content. I've updated the fiddle and code to make it more clear